# Trouble with Pinia mapActions and component visibility of 'getData()' method - why is 'this.getData' working?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-component, pinia

i'm using Pinia for storage variables and functions, i define getData() in the store.

```
  
getData(){
      apiClient.get()
      .then(res => {
             res.data.forEach(element => this.utenti.push(element))
 })
        .then(console.log('dati aggiornati'))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

I map it in my component using ...mapActions and it works. When i call it in mount i have to write "this.getData" instead of "this.getData()" to make it work and i have not visiblity in component's method

```
..... 

computed: {
    ...mapWritableState(useStore, ['crea', 'utenti', 'propieta']),
    ...mapActions(useStore,['getData'])
 },

mounted() {
    console.log('mounted...')
    this.getData
},

methods: {      
      refresh(){
        console.log('refresh')
    this.getData
},
```

i try a lot of research on the internet but i don't know why i havo to write getData and not getData(), and why i have not visdibility inside methods. Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

`mapActions` is supposed to be used in `methods`:

```
computed: {
    ...mapWritableState(useStore, ['crea', 'utenti', 'propieta']),
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions(useStore,['getData']),
    ...
},
```

Using it in `computed` would result in using action functions as computed getter function, which is a mistake that will result in the described behaviour.